# How do I get a html string into a form that can be used with HTML Agility Pack (and in particular DocumentNode.InnerText)

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, type-conversion

I have some HTML code in string variable `someHtmlCodeInString`. I’m not loading this from a webpage but from somewhere else earlier in my program, with input from the user. My end goal is to get the plaintext without HTML tags from the HTML in string variable `someHtmlCodeInString`.

However, I’m running into a problem. I don’t know how to get `someHtmlCodeInString` into a form that can passed through HTML Agility Pack. In particular, I’m having trouble trying to using `*.DocumentNode.InnerText()`.

```
HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmldoc=someHtmlCodeInString;
Console.Write(“PlainText: “ + htmldoc.DocumentNode.InnerText());
```

How do I get a html string into a form that can be used with HTML Agility Pack (and in particular DocumentNode.InnerText)? The only documentation I’m finding is loading a HTML page from the web into a variable (e.g. `doc.Load(urlVar)`) but I'm loading my HTML code from a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:

There is a .LoadHtml() function for loading in a HTML string, rather than just Load()